# Hiker's Cabin Myster | Pt. XII

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

You continue through the labyrinth by taking passageway

> O.

Now, there's another crossroads with 26 passageways, one for each letter of the alphabet. This is going to be tough, isn't it?

There's also a very well done painting on the wall:

[image]

Which passageway should you take, and why?

---

Note the lack of fluff in this riddle. Sorry about that! I'm in a bit of a hurry and this one won't have any backstory, at all. The next one will, I promise!

---

**Current Points:**
Joshua Bizley -- <strike>24</strike> <strike>19</strike> 14 points

Shoover -- <strike>15</strike> <strike>40</strike> 109 points

Omega Krypton — <strike>40</strike> <strike>60</strike> 67 points

SEE PART XI FOR INFORMATION ON HOW POINTS WORK

Comment: So this puzzle is worth 100 pts, right? I got 27, and shoover 25 atm? Which means there are still 48 more to go?

Comment: @OmegaKrypton - Incorrect (or incomplete) answers are worth a maximum of 30 points. That means you guys are _very_ close!

Comment: @OmegaKrypton - Also, it's a maximum of 100 _per person who attempts_...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar to Omega Krypton, I used the old trick

> on the image link from the original post, not the edited version

and I got

> an image of a 170g container of pear-flavored Ísey Skyr yogurt from Iceland

which is interesting because

> the puffin photo is by Jorunn Sjofn, who lives in Reykjavik, Iceland https://www.flickr.com/people/jorunns/

Also just breaking the "ice" here.

As an aside,

> puffins can be found in Iceland.

In an update, Omega Krypton found

> the string TTTTAOHIKTEOEALNTLOHOCEFA hidden in the yogurt image

which arranges to

> TTTT
>      AOHI
>      KTEO
>      EALN
>      TLO
>      HOC
>      EFA

that is:

> TAKE THE TOTAL OF THE LOCATION

which means that we should take

> ICELAND = 9 + 3 + 5 + 12 + 1 + 14 + 4 = 48, and 48 mod 26 = 22, which is V

Comment: You're at 40 points total now...

Comment: Just noticed that you edited... Exactly right! This should put you at 109 points, now!

Answer (score 3):

Well, here’s my partial answer to break the **ice**.

With no idea what to deal with the puzzle after not getting any results when I open it with notepad, I resorted to the old trick I used (and someone else too)

> Plug the image into the link provided in the last part as a hint: https://manytools.org/hacker-tools/steganography-encode-text-into-image/

And the encoded message says

> ISO7EBd

Aha, and perhaps the first two letters

> is IS, the ISO code of Iceland!

@shoover was clever enough to check the original image as well, and it turned out to be

> an image of a 170g container of pear-flavored Ísey Skyr yogurt from Iceland

and find out that

> the author of the puffin photo, Jorunn Sjofn, lives in Reykjavik, Iceland

I went even one more step forward

> to check the yogurt image

and got

> `TTTTAOHIKTEOEALNTLOHOCEFA`

Comment: Good job! That's 40 + 20 = 60 total so far!

Comment: That’s even better so that makes it a total of 67 points so far. I’ll make the edit soon.

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath is the Iceland clue useful?

Comment: No comment! ;) I can't answer any hints!